# Installing Ubuntu on HP Laptop 2231 tx

Tags: 13.10

I have a HP pavilion g6 2231tx notebook with me and it comes with default windows 8 . But now i need to change the OS to Ubuntu and will i have to face some problem if i do so.One of my friend told me that there is some UEFI problems, can anyone please help me to clear my doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295 ,i hope this will help  you!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.